# How to get subsubdocuments without the subdocumnet field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm having a problem using the command find, I have a field campocr that have a lot of subdocuments for exemple: 106719747_112240747078637_2436802243143511917_n and then I have the subsubdocuments like  textoextraido1.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "CCZTn4lHmIh",
    "campocr" : {
        "106719747_112240747078637_2436802243143511917_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Canais investigados pelo STF\nTe atualizei\nDr Marcelo Frazão*\nTerça Livre TV\nm\n=\nN\ncs\n=>\n=\nSN\nCarla Zambelli\nOswaldo Eustáquio\nFoco do Brasil\nBernardo P Kúuster\no\n?\n7\n6\no\no\n<\n&\n+ + +\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "Canais investigados pelo STF\nTe atualizei\nDr Marcelo Frazão*\n= 7\nR Ss\nPR o\ns E\n-\nx\no\n.\n|\n-\no\nCarla Zambelli\nOswaldo Eustáquio\nFoco do Brasil\nBernardo P Kúuster\no\n?\n7\nsã\no\no\n<\n&\nKR + +\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "Canais investigados pelo STF\nTe atualizei\nDr Marcelo Frazão*\nTerça Livre TV\nEnzuh\nCarla Zambelli\nOswaldo Fustáquic\nFoco do Brasil\nBernardo P Kuster\nRADAR\nAF\n",
            "opcao" : 2,
            "gabarito" : "Canais investigados pelo STF\nTe atualizei\nDr Marcelo Frazão*\nTerça Livre TV\nEnzuh\nCarla Zambelli\nOswaldo Eustáquio\nFoco do Brasil\nBernardo P Kuster\nRADAR AF\n"
        },
        "106734782_181302733405757_4000795843436713477_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Os canais que mais transitam em grupos\nbolsonaristas\nNE Investigados pelo STF\nTerça Livre TV\nrá\nPAPO CONSERVADOR com GUSTAVO GAYER\nDr Marcelo Frazão\nTe atualizei\nNossa Rede Brasil\n34\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "Os canais que mais transitam em grupos\nbolsonaristas\nNE Investigados pelo STF\nTerça Livre TV\nE\nN\nPAPO CONSERVADOR com GUSTAVO GAYER\nDr Marcelo Frazão\nTe atualizei\nNossa Rede Brasil\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "Os canais que mais transitam em grupos\nbolsonaristas\nE Investigados pelo STF\nTerça Livre TV\nré\nPAPO CONSERVADOR com GUSTAVO GAYER\nDr Marcelo Frazão\nTe atualize\"\nNossa Rede Brasil\nRADAR AF\n",
            "opcao" : 1,
            "gabarito" : "Os canais que mais transitam em grupos\nbolsonaristas\nInvestigados pelo STF\nTerça Livre TV\nPAPO CONSERVADOR com GUSTAVO GAYER\nDr Marcelo Frazão\nTe atualizei\nNossa Rede Brasil\nRADAR AF\n"
        },
        "106912608_4765797586779104_6329178112583690206_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Desinformação do WhatsApp ao\nYouTube\nMN Vídeos que citam a China\nExpropriação na Argentina\nPolítica brasileira\nCoronavírus\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "Desinformação do WhatsApp ao\nYouTube\nMN Vídeos que citam a China\nExpropriação na Argentina\nPolítica brasileira\nCoronavírus\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "Desinformação do WhatsApp ao\nYouTube\nMN Vídeos que citam a China\nExpropriação na Argentina\nPolítica brasileira\nCoronavírus\nRADAR AF\n",
            "opcao" : 1,
            "gabarito" : "Desinformação do WhatsApp ao\nYouTube\nVídeos que citam a China\nExpropriação na Argentina\nPolítica brasileira\nCoronavírus\nRADAR AF\n"
        },
        "106626782_204495654206351_4462181095498446162_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Os temas mais abordados nos vídeos\ncriticas à imprensa\nminimizações da pandemia\ncríticas a governador(es)\ncríticas ao inquérito das fake naws\ncríticas ao STF\no vV bd o %\n%\n<\n&\n&\ns\no\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "Os temas mais abordados nos videos\ncriticas à imprensa\nminimizações da pandemia\ncríticas a governador(es)\ncríticas ao inquérito das fake news\ncríticas ao STF\no\n?\nvs\n6\nE\no\n<\nf&\n“\ne\nw\nRADAR)» AF\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "Os temas mais abordados nos videos\ncriticas à imprensa\nminimizações da pandemia\ncríticas a governador(es)\ncríticas ao inquérito das fake naws\ncríticas ao STF\nRADAR AF\n",
            "opcao" : 1,
            "gabarito" : "Os temas mais abordados nos vídeos\ncriticas à imprensa\nminimizações da pandemia\ncríticas a governador(es)\ncríticas ao inquérito das fake news\ncríticas ao STF\nRADAR AF\n"
        }
    },
    "fonte" : "aosfatos"
}
```

I would like to project something like:

```
db.mycollection.find({},{'campocr.$.textoextraido1'})
```

and would return this:

```
"106719747_112240747078637_2436802243143511917_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Canais investigados pelo STF\nTe atualizei\nDr Marcelo Frazão*\nTerça Livre TV\nm\n=\nN\ncs\n=>\n=\nSN\nCarla Zambelli\nOswaldo Eustáquio\nFoco do Brasil\nBernardo P Kúuster\no\n?\n7\n6\no\no\n<\n&\n+ + +\nRADAR)» AF\n"
             },
        "106734782_181302733405757_4000795843436713477_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Os canais que mais transitam em grupos\nbolsonaristas\nNE Investigados pelo STF\nTerça Livre TV\nrá\nPAPO CONSERVADOR com GUSTAVO GAYER\nDr Marcelo Frazão\nTe atualizei\nNossa Rede Brasil\n34\nRADAR)» AF\n"
        },
        "106912608_4765797586779104_6329178112583690206_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Desinformação do WhatsApp ao\nYouTube\nMN Vídeos que citam a China\nExpropriação na Argentina\nPolítica brasileira\nCoronavírus\nRADAR)» AF\n"
        },
        "106626782_204495654206351_4462181095498446162_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Os temas mais abordados nos vídeos\ncriticas à imprensa\nminimizações da pandemia\ncríticas a governador(es)\ncríticas ao inquérito das fake naws\ncríticas ao STF\no vV bd o %\n%\n<\n&\n&\ns\no\nRADAR)» AF\n"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts the document to an array with `k` and `v` elements allowing you to project the field you want with `v.field`, and then converting the array back to an object.

```json
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "campocr": {
        "$objectToArray": "$campocr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "campocr.k": 1,
      "campocr.v.textoextraido1": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "campocr": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$campocr"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Demo of it working with your example:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/1-j8VLtC1iZ